# Помогите обновить данные в CoreData swift

Tags: swift, coredata

Доброго всем дня, ночи.

Пытаюсь изучать CoreData и банально не могу понять как проверить и обновить данные.

вот такой код у меня, но как это обновить :(

```
 // Проверяем добавленн уже в список продукт или нет
        // Обновляем CoreData со ячейкой 

        let row = self.test[indexPath.row].valueForKey("productName")!
        let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Products")

        if let fetchResults = try!managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject] {

            for i in 0..<fetchResults.count {
                if String(fetchResults[i].valueForKey("productName")!) == row as! String {

                    // Обновляем наши данные

                    // Если у нас false 0 то устанавливаем true 1, и все наоборот

                    if (fetchResults[i].valueForKey("addedToList")!.boolValue == true) {
                        managedObjectContext.setValue(0, forKey: "addedToList")
                    } else {
                        managedObjectContext.setValue(1, forKey: "addedToList")
                    }

                    try!managedObjectContext.save()
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция сохранения в  **swift 3**

```
func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please translate your answer in russian.

Answer (score 0):

Вот как это работает в swift 3.0

```
func saveContext () {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    //Тут мы говорим, что если есть изменение - то сохранять данные еще раз
    if context.hasChanges {
        appDelegate.saveContext()
    }
}
```

Доступен также второй вариант

```
func saveContext () {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    //Тут мы говорим, что если есть изменение - то сохранять данные еще раз
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
          //Здесь мы просто сохраняемся  
          try context.save()
        } catch {
            //Второй вариант это если нету сохранения - то выдает ошибку
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```